# when i use the to_ categorical ,but have a MemoryError

Tags: python, keras

when i use the lstm to comlete the multi-class label,i use the y_train as my label input.

the code below:

```
y_train = yuantrain['LOCF']
labels = to_categorical(np.array(y_train),286)
```

**the error code  hint:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-55-4ae3f21f520f>", line 1, in <module>
labels = to_categorical(np.array(y_train))
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\np_utils.py",
line 24, in to_categorical

categorical = np.zeros((n, num_classes))

MemoryError
```

below is the y_train(5) :

```
In [65]: 
y_train[0:5]
Out[65]: 
0    620245
1       282
2    500004
3    620193
4     60119
Name: LOCF, dtype: int64
```

THAT I HAVE A TRY:

```
# biao qian chu li
# 处理标签为二进制，以及思考二进制的解码
labels = yuantrain["LOCF"].drop_duplicates()
#labels is the y_train's unique label
num_labels = len(labels) # (all of the unique labels)
one_hot = np.zeros((num_labels, num_labels), int)
np.fill_diagonal(one_hot, 1)
label_dict = dict(zip(labels, one_hot)) 
y_train = yuantrain['LOCF']
y_train = y_train.apply(lambda y: label_dict[y])
```

BUT I feel it is not easy for me, that i have to decode in only my way.

when i use my one-hot way,the keras also have error like below:

```
Train...
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): SeqOptimizer apply                  <theano.tensor.opt.FusionOptimizer object at 0x000000000D87B0F0>
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Traceback:
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\opt.py", line 235, in apply
sub_prof = optimizer.optimize(fgraph)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\opt.py", line 87, in optimize
ret = self.apply(fgraph, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\opt.py", line 7289, in apply
new_outputs = self.optimizer(node)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\opt.py", line 7122, in local_fuse
tv = gof.op.get_test_value(ii)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py", line 987, in get_test_value
return PureOp._get_test_value(v_var)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py", line 580, in _get_test_value
detailed_err_msg = utils.get_variable_trace_string(v)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\utils.py", line 134, in get_variable_trace_string
return sio.getvalue()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\StringIO.py", line 271, in getvalue
self.buf += ''.join(self.buflist)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): SeqOptimizer apply <theano.tensor.opt.FusionOptimizer object at 0x000000000D87B0F0>
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Traceback:
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\opt.py", line 235, in apply
sub_prof = optimizer.optimize(fgraph)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\opt.py", line 87, in optimize
ret = self.apply(fgraph, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\opt.py", line 7289, in apply
new_outputs = self.optimizer(node)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\opt.py", line  7122, in local_fuse
tv = gof.op.get_test_value(ii)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py", line  987, in get_test_value
return PureOp._get_test_value(v_var)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py", line 580, in _get_test_value
detailed_err_msg = utils.get_variable_trace_string(v)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\utils.py", line  134, in get_variable_trace_string
return sio.getvalue()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\StringIO.py", line 271, in getvalue
self.buf += ''.join(self.buflist)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)
Train on 100000 samples, validate on 77963 samples
Epoch 1/5
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-67-5ce4b6739b03>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('E:/XIAMENproject/Prediction_Guo/count.py',   wdir='E:/XIAMENproject/Prediction_Guo')
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
File "E:/XIAMENproject/Prediction_Guo/count.py", line 150, in <module>
validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 870, in fit
initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1507, in fit
initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1156, in _fit_loop
outs = f(ins_batch)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\theano_backend.py", line 1196, in __call__
return self.function(*inputs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 805, in __call__
self.maker.inputs[i].variable)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\utils.py", line 134, in get_variable_trace_string
return sio.getvalue()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\StringIO.py", line 271, in getvalue
self.buf += ''.join(self.buflist)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 27:  ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide us with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please tell the community what are you doing to try, what you actuall problem is and what you have tried. Also please format your post (the code snippets). And give us all informations needed to understand your problem. What is n, num_classes etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

I reset the tag ID to the continuous ID,and then use the to_categorical.

Comment: before solve the problem the y which is 611000011 is out bound